# Changing the format of two columns using AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the below data as input:

```
A 1,2
B 3,2,5
C 6,7
D 1,3,5,8
```

How can I get the below output using AWK?

```
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 2
B 5
C 6
C 7
D 1
D 3
D 5
D 8
```

Comment: This is a work order, not a question. Isn't any demonstrated effort required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[ ,]' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) print $1, $i }' file
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 2
B 5
C 6
C 7
D 1
D 3
D 5
D 8
```

This treats the lines as consisting of fields delimited by either spaces or commas.  For each line, the `awk` program iterates over the second field onwards to the end of the line.  For each field, it outputs the *first* field on the line together with the current field.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,  "\n" $1 " "); print}' file
```

In this solution we are just replacing every "`,`" by `"\n$1 "`

Comment: Non-obvious, but sweet and precise.

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is an option, you could do:

```
sed -E ':a s/^([^ ]* )(.*),([^,]*$)/\1\2\n\1\3/; ta' infile
```

considering below input:

```
B 2,3,5,6
C 6,7
D 1,3,5,8
```

1. This `([^ ]* )` capture first column (assuming space is a delimiter); it will capture `B`  (*B* followed by a *space*).
2. This `(.*),` capture everything until last comma seen; it will capture `2,3,5`
3. This `([^,]*$)` captures the rest of the line (ie: last field after last comma every time); it will capture `6`

   - so `\1\2\n\1\3` would result as below at first loop-run for first line:

     ```
     sed -E ':a s/^([^ ]* )(.*),([^,]*$)/\1\2\n\1\3/;q ;ta' infile 
     B 2,3,5
     B 6
     ```
   - next loop-run it would result as below:

     ```
     B 2,3
     B 5
     B 6
     ```
   - next run ...
   - finally in last loop-run for first line will output as below:

     ```
     sed -E ':a s/^([^ ]* )(.*),([^,]*$)/\1\2\n\1\3/ ;ta ;q' infile
     B 2
     B 3
     B 5
     B 6
     ```
   - now read next line and do the same process until all lines proceed and finished.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` with the extended regex engine enabled we can do as shown:

```
$ sed -re '
   s/^((\S+\s+)[^,]+),/\1\n\2/
   P;D
' file
```

With `Perl` we can do as :

```
$ perl -F'\s+|,' -lane '
   print join $", splice @F, 0, 2, $F[0] while @F > 1;
' file
```

Split the current record on either a run of whitespace or comma and store in zero indexed array `@F`.

Splice the first two elements of the array and join them with single space `$"` and print them. Also at the same time replace the two removed elements with the first. Repeat this process till only a single element remains.

Comment: But the question said AWK, not sed or Perl(?).

Comment: Yes that is correct. But many good awk solutions were already provided. So what do you want me to do  , take down the answer?

Comment: "Many" apparently means "two" awk solutions: one excellent and very clear, and one mediocre. Everything else is a masterpiece of unmaintainable obscurity.